# Having trouble getting rid of a program in Linux starting to think it might be malware

Tags: linux, installation-package

Trying to remove a program called touchpad-indicator in Linux, from the repo ppa:atareao/atareao.  I keep getting a message :

```
(synaptic:5226): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_child_watch_add_full: assertion 'pid > 0' failed
(Reading database ... 385982 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing touchpad-indicator (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0) ...
/usr/sbin/deluser: The group `input' does not exist.
dpkg: error processing package touchpad-indicator (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 touchpad-indicator
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
```

Anyone know what is going on with that and how to fix it?  Thanks.

P.S. The first time I tried to uninstall it, it locked my system up, and the icon for it would not disappear from the panel, even though it was supposedly uninstalled -- at least up to the point of giving that same error above.

Edit:  I followed the suggestion of Mokubai.  Linux newbie here.  After I added the group input and added myself as a member, I ran the remove command again.  I got the following output :

```
sudo apt remove touchpad-indicator
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  touchpad-indicator
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1,382 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 385982 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing touchpad-indicator (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0) ...
Removing user `steve' from group `input' ...
Done.
```

I do not see any errors, the process went so fast I could not read anything as it was executing.  But I believe it removed the package touchpad-indicator.  Am I correct?  Thank you

Edit 2: Ran the command to check if it was uninstalled, did not see anywhere in the input that it specifically was here is the output :

```
Commandline: apt-get install touchpad-indicator
Install: python3-evdev:amd64 (0.4.1-0ubuntu3, automatic), python3-pyudev:amd64 (0.16.1-2build1, automatic), gir1.2-rsvg-2.0:amd64 (2.40.2-1, automatic), python3-xlib:amd64 (0.14+20091101-1ubuntu3~trusty, automatic), touchpad-indicator:amd64 (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0)
Commandline: apt-get remove touchpad-indicator
Remove: touchpad-indicator:amd64 (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0)
Remove: touchpad-indicator:amd64 (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0)
Remove: touchpad-indicator:amd64 (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0)
Remove: python3-evdev:amd64 (0.4.1-0ubuntu3), python3-pyudev:amd64 (0.16.1-2build1), gir1.2-rsvg-2.0:amd64 (2.40.2-1), python3-xlib:amd64 (0.14+20091101-1ubuntu3~trusty), touchpad-indicator:amd64 (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0)
Remove: touchpad-indicator:amd64 (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0)
Remove: touchpad-indicator:amd64 (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0)
Remove: touchpad-indicator:amd64 (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0)
Remove: touchpad-indicator:amd64 (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0)
Remove: touchpad-indicator:amd64 (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0)
Commandline: apt-get remove touchpad-indicator
Remove: touchpad-indicator:amd64 (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0)
Commandline: apt-get remove touchpad-indicator
Remove: touchpad-indicator:amd64 (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0)
Remove: touchpad-indicator:amd64 (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0)
Remove: touchpad-indicator:amd64 (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0)
Commandline: apt-get remove touchpad-indicator
Remove: touchpad-indicator:amd64 (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0)
Remove: touchpad-indicator:amd64 (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0)
Commandline: apt-get remove touchpad-indicator
Remove: touchpad-indicator:amd64 (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0)
Commandline: apt-get remove touchpad-indicator
Remove: touchpad-indicator:amd64 (2.2.1-0extras19.04.0)
```

It looks to me like a bunch of command line entries of the remove command but I do not see anything about it having actually removed the package.  Am I reading this incorrectly?  As I said, Linux newbie here.  Thanks

Edit 2 : ran the dgrep command in terminal and this was the output :

```
ii  accountsservice-ubuntu-touch-schemas                        0.0.1+14.04.20140401-0ubuntu1                       all          Transitional package for accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas
ii  gsettings-ubuntu-touch-schemas                              0.0.1+14.04.20140401-0ubuntu1                       all          Transitional package for gsettings-ubuntu-schemas
ii  ktouch                                                      4:4.14.2-0ubuntu1~ubuntu14.04~ppa2                  amd64        touch typing tutor for KDE
ii  ktouch-data                                                 4:4.14.2-0ubuntu1~ubuntu14.04~ppa2                  all          data files for ktouch
ii  libmtdev1:amd64                                             1.1.4-1ubuntu1                                      amd64        Multitouch Protocol Translation Library - shared library
ii  libsoundtouch0:amd64                                        1.7.1-5                                             amd64        Sound stretching library
ii  libts-0.0-0:amd64                                           1.0-12                                              amd64        touch screen library
ii  printer-driver-ptouch                                       1.3-8                                               amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
rc  touchpad-indicator                                          2.2.1-0extras19.04.0                                all          An indicator for the touchpad
ii  tsconf                                                      1.0-12                                              all          touch screen library common files
ii  ubuntu-touch-sounds                                         13.10.1                                             all          sounds for the Ubuntu Touch image
```

Thanks

Comment: You are getting an error `The group 'input' does not exist.` So what happens if you do an `addgroup input` before the remove command?

Comment: Then it says I am not a member of the group input.  Linux newbie here, so I will have to figure out how to join that group on my system

Comment: Please add the output of ```dpkg -l | grep touch``` to your question.

Comment: this group input should always exist, it's used to set permissions of various devices (eg: /dev/input/* ). The fact that it's not here might have been a bug in the install scripts of your extra package (which is trying to remove it again and should probably be using --only-if-empty but one can't know).

Comment: A.B that is very interesting and useful information to know, as one tries to learn more about Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `dpkg -l | grep touch` tells you that the package was uninstalled, but a few configuration files are left. Run `sudo apt purge touchpad-indicator` to get rid of them, too.

Answer (score -1):

It likely did; but this:
 `sudo grep touchpad-indicator /var/log/apt/history.log` will confirm or deny.